# Nrwl Nx build for production missing node modules bundle

Tags: express, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I have a Nrwl Nx repo with different apps (angular, nodejs with express) and shared libs inside.
The repo was created with the `nx cli` and I want to build for production one of the `express` apps.

```
nx build:production myexpressapp
```

The bundle I get is very nice and runs if I run it (with pm2) from where it was built (`dist` folder). 
However, if I get it to production, the node modules are missing and the app does not start.
If I copy the node_modules folder above the one with the built dist it works as well.

But I would very much like either of:

- Getting a big bundle with all the required modules inside of it?
- Getting another 'vendors' bundle along my main one where all the needed modules are?

I tried using  `"vendorChunk":true` in my production build options but nothing changes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at `angular.json` (or `workspace.json`), if your `builder` is `@nrwl/node:build`, under `options`, set `externalDependencies` to `none`, like so:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "api": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "options": {
            "externalDependencies": "none"
            ...
```

You may experience errors like:

```
ERROR in ...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'some-modules' in ...
```

Just keep installing what its complaining about, until it stops.

Reference: [Nrwl Nx Node Builder](https://nx.dev/angular/plugins/node/builders/build#externaldependencies)

Comment: Impressive! I have been living in the dark for so long. :) It does indeed work. Thanks

Comment: One of the few times in which I got the perfect answer I needed in no time!

Comment: Thank you. This was so hard to find.

Comment: This seems to bundle everyting in the node_modules, even things the app itself does not need... I am using NestJS and it complains that @nestjs/microservices cannot be found, even though I'm not using it in the project. When I install them, it complains that grpc, mqtt, redis and bunch of others are also not installed. I don't think I want to bundle everything with the app, only the modules it actually uses.

Comment: I have explicitly specified the externalDependencies: "all" in build target options (workspace.json) and I am still experiencing the issue.

Comment: correct doc reference  https://nx.dev/node/webpack#externaldependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you're missing the `node_modules` folder entirely, you need to add the  `generatePackageJson` option to your project.json

Like so:

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:webpack",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "...",
        "main": "...",
        "tsConfig": "...",
        "assets": [...],
        "generatePackageJson": true,
        "target": "node",
        "compiler": "tsc"
      },
    ...
```